# Configuration of ul li tags with Jquery Tree Plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have the following code which is generating the dynamic tree structure in ul li tag using PHP (Codeigniter).

Following is the PHP code where I am fetching data from preorder traversal table:

```
function renderTree($tree, $currDepth = -1) {
  $currNode = array_shift($tree);
  $result = '';
  // Going down?
  if ($currNode['depth'] > $currDepth) {
    // Yes, prepend <ul>
    $result .= '<ul>';
  }
  // Going up?
  if ($currNode['depth'] < $currDepth) {
    // Yes, close n open <ul>
    $result .= str_repeat('</ul>', $currDepth - $currNode['depth']);
  }
  // Always add the node
  $result .= '<li>' . $currNode['name'] . '</li>';
  // Anything left?
  if (!empty($tree)) {
    // Yes, recurse
    $result .=  renderTree($tree, $currNode['depth']);
  }
  else {
    // No, close remaining <ul>
    $result .= str_repeat('</ul>', $currNode['depth'] + 1);
  }
  return $result;
}

print renderTree($tree);
```

And it will generate the following tree structure according to the records in table:

```
<ul>
    <li>Language</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>PHP</li>
            <li>Java</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Hybernet</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Web</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>HTML</li>
                    <li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>HTML Canvas</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Ruby</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to use Jquery tree plugin for animating it. Means I can hide and expand the parent-child of it same like explorer or any hierarchical tree module. But because of this generating dynamically I am facing problem on it and not getting how can I configure it with jquery. I need help on it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the TreeMenu.js and follow their documentation. Its easy for configuration:

http://mackpexton.com/projects/TreeMenu/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

put id="tree" on your UL

Assuming you are using http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

then put some js along the lines of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#tree").treeview({
            collapsed: true,
            animated: "fast",
            prerendered: true,
            persist: "location"
        });
    })

</script>
```

it should just work ok , be sure to read the docs and examples from the jquery plugin site linked.

Comment: I tried it but it showing the following error into the above js: `$("#tree").treeview is not a function
[Break On This Error] persist: "location" `

Comment: I am using the following plugin : `jquery.treeview.async.js`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but I've made a jsfiddle for you with expand/collapse categories. You can do it yourself without using any plugin, but again I don't know if that is what you want

CSS

```
div.tree ul li {
    display:block;
}

div.tree ul li ul {
    display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="tree">
<ul> 
    <li>Language <a href="#">expand</a>
        <ul> 
            <li>PHP</li> 
            <li>Java                
                 <ul> 
                    <li>Hybernet</li> 
                 </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Web
                <ul> 
                    <li>HTML
                        <ul> 
                            <li>HTML Canvas</li> 
                        </ul> 
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
            </li> 
            <li>Ruby</li> 
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li>Other menu <a href="#">expand</a>

        <ul> 
            <li>Other submenu</li>
</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.tree ul li a').click(function(){

        var a = $(this).next('ul');
        if(a.css('display') == 'block') {
               a.css('display','none');    
               $(this).html('expand');
        } else {
               a.css('display','block');    
               $(this).html('collapse');   
        }    
    });
});
```

[Your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VF8nw/)